# Using SOQL with ExactTarget, how to I access the "System Data View"?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

Trying to fetch subscriber data from a specific list from ExactTarget.

When querying the "System Data View", an error is returned saying "System Data View cannot be accessed" - which might be disabled, though it is unclear how to enable it.

Using SOQL with ExactTarget, how to I access the "System Data View"?

Answer (score 1):

System Data Views in Exacttarget are currently not available using SOQL.  You would need to access System Data Views using Query Activities.  More information on this is available [in the documentation here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/)